# T-SQL: Add NOT NULL constraint to multiple existing columns at once

Tags: t-sql, constraints

I have a table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (
   Text int, 
   column2 varchar(50),
   column3 varchar(50)
)
```

and now I would like using T-SQL to apply a NOT NULL constraints to the three columns at once (Note that I have a column called Text that matches with a reserved type in T-SQL), so I perform:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT NOT_NULL NOT NULL (Text, column2, column3)
```

but it is not working:

Incorrect syntax near reserved word 'not'.

Comment: ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN [Text] int NOT NULL;

Comment: Basically, you can't do all three at once.  You have to issue a command for each column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, your syntax is wrong.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ALTER COLUMN column2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

Note that `NOT NULL` doesn't quite behave as a constraint, but rather a feature of the column's type. As such, you don't use the `ADD CONSTRAINT` operation.

Secondly, you just have to use multiple statements, one for each column. There's really no benefit to adding the constraints all at once, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The `NOT NULL` thing is not a constraint, but is part of the data type of the column, so the `ADD CONSTRAINT` don't applies at all to begin with. The correct way to do is to use an `ALTER COLUMN`, so the correct syntax would be

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN [Text] INT NOT NULL,
                                     [column2] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                                     [column3] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ;
```

The thing of the column name colliding with the reserved keyword is deal with by enclosing the name in [], but that's not the original problem in your example.

Comment: This gives `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ','.` (in SQL Server 2012) because you cannot alter more than one column at a time. You must do multiple `ALTER TABLE...ALTER COLUMN` statements to modify one at a time, as stated in the accepted answer.